# Find first instance of specific value and add ID, repeated

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, filtering

Given a series of div's with known values is it possible to create a filter or array that finds the first instance of the values and adds an ID over multiple items? Here's the basic structure:

```
<div class="boxes">
  <div class="box"><time>2017</time></div>
  <div class="box"><time>2016</time></div>
  <div class="box"><time>2015</time></div>
  <div class="box"><time>2014</time></div>
  <div class="box"><time>2014</time></div>
  <div class="box"><time>2014</time></div>
  <div class="box"><time>2013</time></div> 
</div>
```

And here's the snippet I'm using to find one of the values:

```
var elems = $('.box').filter(function(){
 return this.textContent.trim() === "2014"
}).first().attr('id', 'one');
```

I'm not sure the best way to go about looking for additional instances?

For example, it feels like there's a better way than simply repeating the argument. The novice in me admittedly does not know what this type of function would be called.

```
var elems = $('.box').filter(function(){
 return this.textContent.trim() === "2014"
}).first().attr('id', 'one');

var elems = $('.box').filter(function(){
 return this.textContent.trim() === "2017"
}).first().attr('id', 'one');
```

It would be a bonus to not have to add the specific value, i.e. 2017 (`<time id="one">2017</time>`), 2016 (`<time id="two">2016</time>`) but I'm not even sure if that's realistic.

Working Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/heykenneth/gn4gmvt0/1/.

Comment: If anyone is curious, I'm using this for a dynamically generated timeline with milestones, where I'm going to use the years to create an anchor nav allowing a jump to specific years.

Comment: Wrap your code in a loop such as `for(var year = 2014; year <= 2017; year++) { var elems.....filter( function() { this.textContent.trim() === year;}) ....}`

Comment: Does cale_b's answer help?
@Ken what do you mean by "It would be a bonus to not have to add the specific value"

Comment: @xadhix I'm looking to keep the id's unique, so that each instance gets a different ID. It would be nice if you didn't need to know the value of the item only that it was the first instance of that value you in the series. Yes, cale_b's suggestion is helpful!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this by wrapping up parameters of the code you've already written:

```js
markFirstYear("2014", "one");
markFirstYear("2015", "two");
markFirstYear("2016", "three");
markFirstYear("2017", "four");
// ... etc

function markFirstYear(year, id) {
  var elems = $('.box').filter(function(){
   return this.textContent.trim() === year
  }).first().attr('id', id);
}
```

```css
#one {color:red;}
#two {color:blue;}
#three {color:green;}
#four {color:purple;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="boxes">
  <div class="box"><time>2017</time></div>
  <div class="box"><time>2016</time></div>
  <div class="box"><time>2015</time></div>
  <div class="box"><time>2014</time></div>
  <div class="box"><time>2014</time></div>
  <div class="box"><time>2014</time></div>
  <div class="box"><time>2013</time></div> 
</div>
```

Comment: this is what I'm after as it accomplishes the additional req of having unique ID's for each item. Appreciate the insight.

Answer (score 3):

First create array of all values you have, then just get unique values from that array and finally iterate through `unique` array.

```js
var myArr = new Array();

$('.box time').each(function(){
    myArr.push($(this).text());
});

var unique = myArr.filter(function(item, index, array) {
    return index == myArr.indexOf(item);
});

for (var i = 0; i <= unique.length; i++) { 
 var elems = $('.box').filter(function() {
   return this.textContent.trim() === unique[i];
 }).first().attr('class', 'one');
}
```

```css
.one {color:red;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="boxes">
  <div class="box"><time>2017</time></div>
  <div class="box"><time>2016</time></div>
  <div class="box"><time>2015</time></div>
  <div class="box"><time>2014</time></div>
  <div class="box"><time>2014</time></div>
  <div class="box"><time>2014</time></div>
  <div class="box"><time>2013</time></div> 
</div>
```

Comment: very slick. Is it possible create unique ID's vs adding a class over the series? i.e. `<div id="one"><time>2017</time></div>`, `<div id="two"><time>2016</time></div>`, etc.? The ID's will be used for an anchor nav.

Comment: @Ken Yes it is. Also I was under impression that you wanted everything automated in the accepted answer you have to target the year you want to use.

Comment: the automation is ideal, however I'm not sure how I would give each instance a unique ID in an automated fashion without targeting the specific value.

Comment: @Ken Pretty easy just use `i` variable from loop